# object has method apply when calling wrapAsync

Tags: facebook, meteor

i get this error :

```
Object <object> has no method apply
```

when calling this function

```
 var fb = new Facebook(Meteor.user().services.facebook.accessToken);
        data =Meteor.wrapAsync(fb.query("/search?q=" + keywords + "&type=page&fields=name,category,can_post,likes,link,location,emails,phone"));
on server side.
```

**Update : 
after trying this :**

```
   var fb = new Facebook(Meteor.user().services.facebook.accessToken);
        var fbQuerySync = Meteor.wrapAsync(fb.query, fb);
        var data = fbQuerySync("/search?q=" + keywords + "&type=page&fields=name,category,can_post,likes,link,location,emails,phone");
```

**i get this error**

```
    Error inside the Async.runSync: Property 'function (/* arguments */) {                                                                     // 99
W20150402-21:30:07.620(0)? (STDERR)     var args = _.toArray(arguments);                                                                      // 100
W20150402-21:30:07.620(0)? (STDERR)                                                                                                           // 101
W20150402-21:30:07.620(0)? (STDERR)     var runWithEnvironment = function () {                                                                // 102
W20150402-21:30:07.620(0)? (STDERR)       var savedValues = Fiber.current._meteor_dynamics;                                                   // 103
W20150402-21:30:07.620(0)? (STDERR)       try {                                                                                               // 104
W20150402-21:30:07.620(0)? (STDERR)         // Need to clone boundValues in case two fibers invoke this                                       // 105
W20150402-21:30:07.620(0)? (STDERR)         // function at the same time                                                                      // 106
W20150402-21:30:07.621(0)? (STDERR)         Fiber.current._meteor_dynamics = _.clone(boundValues);                                            // 107
W20150402-21:30:07.621(0)? (STDERR)         var ret = func.apply(_this, args);                                                                // 108
W20150402-21:30:07.621(0)? (STDERR)       } catch (e) {                                                                                       // 109
W20150402-21:30:07.621(0)? (STDERR)         // note: callback-hook currently relies on the fact that if onException                           // 110
W20150402-21:30:07.621(0)? (STDERR)         // throws and you were originally calling the wrapped callback from                               // 111
W20150402-21:30:07.621(0)? (STDERR)         // within a Fiber, the wrapped call throws.                                                       // 112
W20150402-21:30:07.622(0)? (STDERR)         onException(e);                                                                                   // 113
W20150402-21:30:07.622(0)? (STDERR)       } finally {                                                                                         // 114
W20150402-21:30:07.622(0)? (STDERR)         Fiber.current._meteor_dynamics = savedValues;                                                     // 115
W20150402-21:30:07.622(0)? (STDERR)       }                                                                                                   // 116
W20150402-21:30:07.622(0)? (STDERR)       return ret;                                                                                         // 117
W20150402-21:30:07.622(0)? (STDERR)     };                                                                                                    // 118
W20150402-21:30:07.623(0)? (STDERR)                                                                                                           // 119
W20150402-21:30:07.623(0)? (STDERR)     if (Fiber.current)                                                                                    // 120
W20150402-21:30:07.623(0)? (STDERR)       return runWithEnvironment();                                                                        // 121
W20150402-21:30:07.623(0)? (STDERR)     Fiber(runWithEnvironment).run();                                                                      // 122
```

OUPS :
the method is already sync it seems here's another piece of code:

```
Facebook.prototype.query = function(query, method) {
    var self = this;
    var method = (typeof method === 'undefined') ? 'get' : method;
    var data = Meteor.sync(function(done) {
        self.fb[method](query, function(err, res) {
            done(null, res);
        });
    });
    return data.result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var fb = new Facebook(Meteor.user().services.facebook.accessToken);
var fbQuerySync = Meteor.wrapAsync(fb.query, fb);
var data = fbQuerySync("/search?q=" + keywords + "&type=page&fields=name,category,can_post,likes,link,location,emails,phone");
```

The problem with your code is that you pass the wrong parameters to `Meteor.wrapAsync`, it's expecting a function and an eventual context if the passed function is intended to be used as a method.

What you obtain as a result is a synchronous function that you can use in the Meteor context.